Spring transaction rollback can’t throw right Exception message catched in Service
How can I use declarative annotations in a Spring project to ensure that the exception information is still returned properly on rollback?
As an example, I typed the annotation @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class) on top of the service layer, class
, then in the service method I wrote try catch block, in the catch I wrote throw new BusinessExceputon(e.getMessage());
  try{
   …
}catch(Exception e){
  throw new BusinessException(e.getMessage());
}

my intention is, when an exception occurs, catch the exception, then give specific exception information to the exception to be thrown, and then after being Transactional catch, trigger data rollback at the same time can pass this specific exception information to the Controller layer, so that I write in the Controller layer try catch block, catch to the specific exception information, I can encapsulate it into the Result to provide to the front-end.
  try{
   …
}catch(BusinessException e){
  return BackProResult.returnError(e.getMessage())
}

But the actual scenario is that after catching the exception with @Transactional, the framework seems to rethrow an exception with the rollback... , the specific exception information I want to pass is completely overwritten.
Just a reminder, BusinessException is a custom exception extends Exception.

If the upstream of your service is a REST API, you can refer to @RestControllerAdvice, which can help you globally or locally capture BusinessException and respond with relevant exception information.
